# The listview items are not showing in UI with AbsoluteLayout

Tags: maui

I have a UI with `AbsoluteLayout` like below in my MAUI project:

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <ListView
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
        x:Name="commentlistview"
        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
        RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
        SeparatorColor="#dddddd"
        SelectionMode="None"
        HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout 
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    Margin="15,10"
                    Orientation="Vertical">

                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                            Tapped="CommentItemTapped"
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding commenterName, Converter={StaticResource specialCharactorConverter}}"
                        TextColor="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.TextColor}"
                        Style="{StaticResource CommentBoldListviewStyle}"/>

                        <Label
                        Text="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.comment, Converter={StaticResource specialCharactorConverter}}"
                        TextColor="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.TextColor}"
                        Style="{StaticResource CommentListviewStyle}"/>

                        <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.isImageFile}">

                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage 
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                IsVisible="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.isImageNull}"
                                Source="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.commentFiles, Converter={StaticResource urlJoinConverter}}"
                                VerticalOptions="Fill">
                                <ffimageloading:CachedImage.HeightRequest>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>200</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>300</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>200</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </ffimageloading:CachedImage.HeightRequest>
                                <ffimageloading:CachedImage.WidthRequest>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>200</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>300</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>200</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </ffimageloading:CachedImage.WidthRequest>
                            </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer   
                                    Tapped="ViewFullSizeCommentImage"
                                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout 
                            IsVisible="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.isDocFile}"
                            Orientation="Vertical">

                            <Image 
                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                IsVisible="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.isImageNull}"
                                Source="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.commentFiles, Converter={StaticResource urlJoinConverter}}"
                                VerticalOptions="Fill">
                                <Image.HeightRequest>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>70</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>100</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>70</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Image.HeightRequest>
                                <Image.WidthRequest>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>50</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>75</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>50</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Image.WidthRequest>
                            </Image>
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer
                                    Tapped="CommentImageTapped"
                                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                                </TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout 
                            Padding="5"
                            Margin="0,5"
                            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                            BackgroundColor="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.BGColor}"
                            IsVisible="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.isMultipleAttachments}"
                            Orientation="Vertical">

                            <Image 
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                Source="ic_doc_xx.png">
                                <Image.HeightRequest>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>70</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>100</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>70</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Image.HeightRequest>
                                <Image.WidthRequest>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>50</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>75</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>50</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Image.WidthRequest>
                            </Image>

                            <Label
                                Text="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.fileCount}"
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                TextColor="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.TextColor}"
                                Style="{StaticResource CommentListviewStyle}"/>

                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer
                                    Tapped="ViewCommentAttachments"
                                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                                </TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <StackLayout.HeightRequest>
                                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                    <OnIdiom.Phone>100</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>150</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                    <OnIdiom.Desktop>100</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                </OnIdiom>
                            </StackLayout.HeightRequest>
                            <StackLayout.WidthRequest>
                                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                    <OnIdiom.Phone>200</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>300</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                    <OnIdiom.Desktop>200</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                </OnIdiom>
                            </StackLayout.WidthRequest>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.createdTime, Converter={StaticResource dateTimeConverter}}"
                                TextColor="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.TextColor}"
                                Style="{StaticResource CommentDateListviewStyle}"/>

                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding replyCount}"
                                IsVisible="{Binding replyVisibility}"
                                TextColor="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.TextColor}"
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Style="{StaticResource CommentDateListviewStyle}">
                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Tapped="ViewAllReplies"
                                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Label>

                            <StackLayout
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                IsVisible="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.ReplyVisibility}"
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                                <Image 
                                    Source="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.ArrowSource}">
                                    <Image.WidthRequest>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>23</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Image.WidthRequest>
                                    <Image.HeightRequest>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>23</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Image.HeightRequest>
                                </Image>

                                <Label 
                                    Text="Reply"
                                    TextColor="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.TextColor}"
                                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                    Style="{StaticResource CommentDateListviewStyle}">
                                </Label>
                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Tapped="ReplyTapped"
                                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <Button
                                x:Name="approval_button"
                                Text="Waiting for approval"
                                BackgroundColor="White"
                                TextColor="#f3872c"
                                BorderColor="#f3872c"
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                BorderWidth="1"
                                IsVisible="{Binding parentComment.supportItemComments.ApprovalVisibility}"
                                Style="{StaticResource ApprovalButtonStyle}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.Footer>
            <Label/>
        </ListView.Footer>
    </ListView>

    <ImageButton 
        x:Name="invoices_stack"
        Source="ic_invoice_xx.png"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        IsVisible="false"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"  
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{OnIdiom Phone='.95,.80,50,50', Tablet = '.95,.80,75,75'}" 
        Clicked="invoices_stack_Clicked" />

    <ImageButton 
        x:Name="call_satck"
        Source="ic_requester_call_xx.png"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        IsVisible="false"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"  
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{OnIdiom Phone='.95,.95,50,50', Tablet = '.95,.95,75,75'}" 
        Clicked="StartCall" />

    <Label 
        Style="{StaticResource RequestMessageLabelStyle}"
        Text="No comments"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"  
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".50,.50,150,150"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
        x:Name="commentmessage_label"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

My problem is nothing is visible on the UI with `AbsoluteLayout`. If I remove the `AbsoluteLayout` the listview items are showing. Is the `AbsoluteLayout` properties are deprecated in MAUI?

**Update**

I have created 2 demo samples and uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19bUXeKn8vqDQq6jNPFagOO237RO_sr8e?usp=sharing).

One sample (With AbsoluteLayout) has Absolutelayout where the comments are not listing.

The other sample (Without Absolutelayout) has no Absolutelayout where the comments are listing.

Could you please have a look and tell why the comments are not listing with Absolutelayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your sample. I tested it and fond that the issue is related to the VerticalOptions of AbsoluteLayout, please try setting  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand".

```
<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
```

By the way, I got a AppTransportSecurity error when loading the request on iOS and MacCatalyst platforms, you could add `NSAppTransportSecurity` key in the 'info.plist' file of each platform to ensure the transportation security.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads< /key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

For more details, please refer to [App Transport Security in Xamarin.iOS - Xamarin | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats)(This doc is about Xamarin.iOS, it also appies to MAUI)

Comment: The issue is with the AbsoluteLayout. No issues are with my model, or view model or binding. Without AbsoluteLayout the listview is visible with my data. I am trying to create a sample and share here for reproducing.
I am not using viewmodel class and setting the itemsource value from xaml.cs file.

Comment: I have updated the question with demo sample, could you please have a look?

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can view it.